# How can I delete the content inside a quotation mark in my string?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have this

```
<a href="http://helloword.com"><img src="hola.png" alt="hola"></a>
```

and I need

```
 <a href=""><img src="" alt= ""></a>
```

Comment: Do you really have `href:`?

Comment: what have you tried so far? It looks you need to search for your answer using these words: "how delete text inside quotation marks string python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with regular expressions and did not give me the expected result. What I finally solved the problem was this code . 
I really is more flexible and more dynamic . also allows to save the results into new html files

```
import random
import os
import subprocess
from lxml import html
from lxml.html.clean import clean_html
from lxml.html import tostring, html5parser
import glob
from lxml import html

#print glob.glob("*.html")
for itemfile in glob.glob("*.html"):
    if os.path.isfile(itemfile):
        f = open(itemfile, 'rb')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        dochtml = html.fromstring(data)
        for element, attribute, link, pos in dochtml.iterlinks():
      if element.tag in ("img","a"):
        if attribute == "src":
          element.set('src', "")
          element.set('alt', "")
        if attribute == "href":
          element.set('href', "")
      #print tostring(dochtml)
      parser = tostring(dochtml, method='html')
      f = open(itemfile[:itemfile.find(".html")] + "_parser.html", 'wb')
      f.write(parser)
      f.close()           
    else:
        print 'not file.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below program and it works well for your input. Just check it out.

```
 import re
 s='<a href="http://helloword.com"><img src="hola.png" alt="hola"></a>'
 r=re.sub('".*?"','""',s)
 print r
```

It will print out:

```
<a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: the idea is that I can delete any content that is within those tags. also could be several links or tag.

Comment: Tell me your requirement clearly. You say my solution is not working for you? If so, tell me how

Comment: My intention is not to work for me, but I understand your point. I appreciate that you've given me an idea, I'll try to do the script with regular expressions. regards

Comment: You did not accept my answer and upvote it. :) click on the tick mark near to my answer and click on the up arrow symbol.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy with BeautifulSoup ... i don't know why you use so much code. This will replace the content in this href, alt and src tags with empty string.

I'll use this instead lxml ...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://helloword.com"><img src="hola.png" alt="hola"></a>', 'html.parser')
href = soup.find('a').attrs.get('href')
alt = soup.find('img').attrs.get('alt')
src= soup.find('img').attrs.get('src')

text = str(soup).replace(href, '').replace(src,'').replace(alt,'')
print text
```

Comment: I think it's not much code , if you want to get inside a folder all HTML files , parsing and add new html files with the result. In the code you propose I have to copy and paste html code and get the result by console, but anyway is another excellent choice and I thank you for the contribution.

Comment: It's my example ... if you use requests ... or urllib you don't need to get the code by console :) just: source_code = requests.get(my_url).content